# Left Justifying entry box next to label in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I was wondering why my entry boxes are showing in the center. Before I had the label instructions for first and last name they were aligning right. I have the labels on column 0 and the entry boxes on column 1, however they dont line up directly next to each other. If someone could help me with a very basic solution and language, I am obviously a beginner..

[image: Heres what the GUI looks like]

````
root = Tk()
root.title("Login Information Help")
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry("1920x1080")

def button_click(number):
    textbox.delete(0, END)
    textbox.insert(0, number)

instructions = Label(root, text="Please fill in all information below to recieve student account details.", bg="black", fg="white", font="times, 20") #Create instructions line
first_name_text = Label(root, text="Enter First Name", bg="black", fg="white", font="times, 20" ) #enter first name text
inputbox1 = Entry(root, width=30, font="times, 20") #Create input boxes
last_name_text = Label(root, text="Enter Last Name", bg="black", fg="white", font="times, 20" ) #enter last name text
inputbox2 = Entry(root, width=30, font="Times, 20") #Create input boxes
button_1 = Button(root, text="Get Info", padx=45, pady=5, bg="#808080", font="times, 15", command=lambda: button_click("1")) #Define Buttons

instructions.grid(row=0, column=0) #Define Instructions variables (labels)
first_name_text.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=0, sticky=W) #position first name text
inputbox1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10) #Postion inputbox 1
last_name_text.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W) #position last name text
inputbox2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W) #Postion inputbox 2
button_1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W) #Put Buttons on Screen

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: based on this I assume that since there are two columns the separator is in the middle

Comment: So I changed so that the top label spans 2 columns, helped a little. Is there a way to make it so that the entry boxes can be justified right next to the txt though?

Comment: Put the two label/entry pairs into a frame.

Answer (score 0):

First row must span 2 columns.

```
instructions.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Use `sticky=EW` with every widget to fill the column.

Add `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)` to not expand the first column.

Comment: This gets me closer! However I want the boxes to be right next to the text, I changed the columspan.

Comment: To fill the column you must use `sticky=EW` with every widget and add a `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all this method uses pack since that is what I came up with (more explanation below) here is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, Frame

root = Tk()
root.title("Login Information Help")
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry("1920x1080")

def button_click(number):
    textbox.delete(0, END)
    textbox.insert(0, number)

row0 = Frame(root, bg='black')
row0.pack(side='top', fill='y', anchor='nw')

row1 = Frame(root, bg='black')
row1.pack(side='top', fill='y', anchor='nw')

row2 = Frame(root, bg='black')
row2.pack(side='top', fill='y', anchor='nw')

row3 = Frame(root, bg='black')
row3.pack(side='top', fill='y', anchor='nw')

instructions = Label(row0, text="Please fill in all information below to recieve student account details.", bg="black", fg="white", font="times, 20") #Create instructions line
first_name_text = Label(row1, text="Enter First Name", bg="black", fg="white", font="times, 20" ) #enter first name text
inputbox1 = Entry(row1, width=30, font="times, 20") #Create input boxes
last_name_text = Label(row2, text="Enter Last Name", bg="black", fg="white", font="times, 20" ) #enter last name text
inputbox2 = Entry(row2, width=30, font="Times, 20") #Create input boxes
button_1 = Button(row3, text="Get Info", padx=45, pady=5, bg="#808080", font="times, 15", command=lambda: button_click("1")) #Define Buttons

instructions.pack(side='left')
first_name_text.pack(side='left')
inputbox1.pack(side='left')
last_name_text.pack(side='left')
inputbox2.pack(side='left', padx=2)
button_1.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

**Explanation**: those frames created at the top are stacked like rows, so whenever I add something to each of them using `side` argument in pack they get added there *like columns*, that `padx` is to make the alignment look nicer. Also I would suggest organizing the code better and start learning classes since they imo help a lot when dealing with tkinter.

So basically lets take one of the frames for example. the `row1`: when adding with `.pack`and using one side (left in this case) widgets get packed in a row however it is not that easy to make them then packed in the second row so that is why there is another frame that is directly below the `row1` called `row2` and it gets directly packed underneath because of `top` side similarly as `left` side for widgets and those frames expand only where there are widgets (or maybe for that expansion it has to have the argument of fill, dunno rn) anyhow have a good day and experiment